# Sort python list into dictionary of lists, based on property in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to sort a list of objects in python into a dictionary of lists via a property of the objects in the original list

I've done it below, but this feels like something I should be able to do using a dictionary comprehension?

```
for position in totals["positions"]:
        if not hasattr(totals["positions_dict"], position.get_asset_type_display()):
            totals["positions_dict"][position.get_asset_type_display()] = []
        totals["positions_dict"][position.get_asset_type_display()].append(position)
```

Some self improvements

```
totals["positions_dict"] = {}
    for position in totals["positions"]:
        key = position.get_asset_type_display()
        if key not in totals["positions_dict"]:
            totals["positions_dict"][key] = []
        totals["positions_dict"][key].append(position)
```

Comment: Please post some raw data you've been working on to reproduce your problem.

Comment: it seems it's more calling for a `collections.defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but are you sure your code above works? Especially the hasattr? And you call position.get_asset_type_display () three times to store one value. Better make it efficient by storing in a intermediate var than use a comprehension here. I think it can be done, but you'll end up retrieving data even more times than you did now.

Comment: I think it possibly has a bug, and yes totally right on those extra calls. I usually avoid even minimal optimisation until I know that the code is causing a bottleneck... and works!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) in a dict comprehension:

```
from operator import methodcaller
from itertools import groupby

key = methodcaller('get_asset_type_display')
totals["positions_dict"] = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(totals["positions"], key=key), key=key)}
```

Using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as suggested by @Jean-FrançoisFabre allows you to do it with a single call to `get_asset_type_display()` in one loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

totals["positions_dict"] = defaultdict(list)
for position in totals["positions"]:
    totals["positions_dict"][position.get_asset_type_display()].append(position)
```

Comment: In terms of being "more pythonic" would your version "win" hands down, or could it be a stylistic choice?

Comment: Aside form the crap repeated calls to the key method.

Comment: For your answer, the keys need to come from from the property of the items in the list, which is "asset_type".

So there shouldn't be a call to get a key outside of the function.

Comment: Well, whether this is the best or most performant solution, depends on the cost of the `get_asset_type_display` call. If that is expensive, it would make sense to create an intermediate data structure where you store the `asset_type` for each position.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, because I don't have your data.
And I think it's rather ugly, but it just may work:

```
totals ['positions_dict'] = {
    key: [
        position
        for position in totals ['positions']
        if position.get_asset_type_display () == key
    ]
    for key in {
        position.get_asset_type_display ()
        for position in totals ['positions']
    }
}
```

But I would prefer something very simple, and avoid needless lookups / calls:

```
positions = totals ['positions']
positions_dict = {}

for position in positions:
    key = position.get_asset_type_display ()
    if key in positions_dict:
        positions_dict [key] .append (position)
    else:
        positions_dict [key] = [position]


totals ['positions_dict'] = positions_dict
positions = totals ['positions']
```